# JavaScript Regular Expression to match a number followed by a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a total regex noob and unfortunately could find a regex to match what I need.

I'm in need of a regular expression which will return all of the characters when a number is followed by a letter.

For example: I have an array of strings `[".5a", "2c#", "1e", "2f", "1.5g"]` I would like to get the following array `["a", "c#", "e", "f", "g"]`.

This would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What symbols do you want to match? Just "#"?

Comment: yes just "#" would be great.  I should probably mention that the letters could uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) + regular expression match. Maybe something like this:

```js
var result = [".5aD", "2c#", "1e", "2f", "1.5g"].map(function(str) {
    var m = str.match(/\d(?:\.\d)?([^\d]+)/);
    return m ? m[1] : null;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify( result, null, 4) );
```

Here you can check the explanation of the used regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/pT7oP2/1

Comment: If you only want letters and the # character I would use this `/\d([a-zA-Z#]+)/`

Comment: ok awesome, these do the trick.  Would it be possible to add a slight variation, that if for a particular item there is no number before a letter then just get the letter.  `["1a", "2b", "3.4c", "d"]`  would return `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` instead of null for last item.  And yes I will be using this with either map or forEach.

Comment: Then it can be `return m ? m[1] : str;`